# Hide notifications about a specific question?

Tags: support, reputation, notifications

Is there any way to hide rep notifications about a specific question?

I'm happy when I'm getting a diverse set of notifications relevant to my recent participation on Stack Exchange sites. But it's less pleasing, and almost annoying, when almost every time I click the icon for rep notifications it's about the same old question over and over again. I wrote one [question](https://serverfault.com/q/357108/23300) almost eight years ago that's still getting upvotes, but I'm no longer interested in getting notified about those upvotes.

There are other approaches that might also help to solve my notification fatigue:

- Hide rep notifications about *old* questions/answers (where old is user-defined).
- Hide rep notifications about questions/answers that I haven't engaged with recently.
- Allow me to hide the +10 rep notifications entirely. (I'm still interested in achievements/badges though).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there any way to hide rep notifications about a specific question?

Yes, technically there is: You can make your post belong to the [*community wiki*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).

The flip side up is, that you won't earn any reputation for this post anymore at all when you do this.

What you have is more or less a half baked [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) missing some requirements for a plain, straight [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)<sup>2</sup>.

---

In other words: *Currently there's no way<sup>1</sup> to filter the reputation notifications for specific posts.*

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>I am not sure if such could be done with a client side user script.</sub>
<sup>2)</sup><sub>The [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/feature-request/info) adds some useful information about [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)'s</sub>

Comment: Where can I find the requirements for feature-request? I'm having some trouble on mobile.

Comment: @Nic I've updated my answer regarding that.

Comment: Clever trick - note that you can make your own answers community wiki, but to make your own *question* community wiki you'll need a moderator.