# Will a [discussion] tag make the requirements for a [feature-request] weaker?

Tags: discussion, edits, meta-tags

Inspired by this question: [Hide notifications about a specific question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339658/hide-notifications-about-a-specific-question)

I am wondering if the use of the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag makes the requirements for a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) question weaker than described in the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) *[tagwiki info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/feature-request/info)*? Here's the cite:

> You have an idea for a new feature to be added, or for a change in existing functionality. Great!
>
> Be sure you have thoroughly searched that the feature you are thinking of has not already been proposed. If it has, and it hasn't received a response, follow the advice at [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306397/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unfixed-bug-reports-and-feature-requests-without). If it has already been declined, and you believe that there are new reasons why the team should change their mind, be sure to [clearly address the reasons for originally declining it as well as the new reasons for implementing it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89026/can-we-re-request-features-that-were-declined-a-sufficient-while-ago).
>
> If no proposal exists, then make sure your proposal is in the form of a question [focused on the problem or functional purpose that is driving your perceived need or desire for the new feature](/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378), and *not* focused on what you believe may be the solution for the new feature itself ([your solution is better made as an answer to your question](/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)). So give as much detail and context as possible on the background situation that caused you to bring a feature request and make sure it is formulated to justify why the new feature is needed and/or how it can improve the community. Basically, [prove to the administration](/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying/44189#44189) that they should spend time developing your feature.
>
> Note that voting on feature requests is [based on whether people agree or disagree with your proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta), so if your request gets downvoted, it doesn't necessarily mean that your question is of bad quality; it may just mean that people disagree with your feature suggestion.
>
> [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) is one of the four possible [mandatory tags](/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work/47640#47640); the other mandatory tag options are [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), [support](/questions/tagged/support) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

I have added the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) to the above mentioned questtion, because it basically is a FR:

> Is there any way to hide rep notifications about a specific question?
>
> I'm happy when I'm getting a diverse set of notifications relevant to
>   my recent participation on Stack Exchange sites. But it's less
>   pleasing, and almost annoying, when almost every time I click the icon
>   for rep notifications it's about the same old question over and over
>   again. I wrote one [question](https://serverfault.com/q/357108/23300)
>   almost eight years ago that's still getting upvotes, but I'm no longer
>   interested in getting notified about those upvotes.
>
> There are other approaches that might also help to solve my
>   notification fatigue:
>
> - Hide rep notifications about *old* questions/answers (where old is user-defined).
> - Hide rep notifications about questions/answers that I haven't engaged with recently.
> - Allow me to hide the +10 rep notifications entirely. (I'm still interested in achievements/badges though).

***Update:***

I've retagged the specific question in question with the [support](/questions/tagged/support) tag now, following [@Cody's advice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339666/186472).

Comment: Don't forget - tags have feeds and a sufficiently cultured individual can watch a tag over rss feeds. You can watch *for* tags, not watch *against* tags.

Comment: _@Journey_ It's kinda funny, there's no Meta Meta Stack Exchange site. But well I'll getting into far surreal and bizzare situations. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, no. All feature requests are inherently discussion questions, since they are implicitly soliciting discussion about whether or not implementing the described feature is a good idea. That type of feedback/discussion is what the answers will contain, unless and until a Stack Exchange team member posts an official answer announcing the deployment or rejection of the feature.

Rather than being a descriptor in its own right, the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag is more of a fallback or "catch-all" when nothing else fits. If your question *isn't* either a [support](/questions/tagged/support) request or a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), then it's a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion). In other words, if you *can* be more specific than [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), then you should be.

Regardless of how it's tagged, a good feature request needs to at least attempt to justify why the proposed feature is a good idea.

In the specific case you're citing, I'd say [that question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339658/hide-notifications-about-a-specific-question) is probably more of a [support](/questions/tagged/support) question than a feature request, though. They're asking for help on using the site. Look at the very first line: the asker is wondering if there's a way to do something. Answers should either describe the way, or clarify that there is no way to do that.

Comment: So the correct action with the specific question should have been rather retagging as [tag:support] finally?

Comment: Yes, that's what I would have done. A support request answered with "no, this is not possible" may lead to a feature request, but they're not the same thing.